# MySQL: Filtering JOINed rows

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

Ok, say I have a join query like this:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
LEFT JOIN votes ON (users.id = votes.userid)
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING count(votes.id) >= 0
ORDER BY count(votes.id) LIMIT 0,30
```

Which gets rows from `users`, sorted by the number of rows in the `votes` table with which they have a relationship.

My question: What is the proper way to use a WHERE clause like `WHERE votes.timestamp BETWEEN date_add(NOW(),INTERVAL -24 HOUR) AND NOW()`, such that `users` are sorted only based on the number of rows created in the past 24 hours with which they have relationships?

This makes sense to be able to do, I'm just not really sure where to put it.

Comment: Is there a reason you added `HAVING count(votes.id) >= 0`?  It won't actually have any effect since all columns have a count of 0 or greater...

Comment: I read it here on SO, not sure if I still have the link, but the asker and I had the some problem of rows with no relationships not being returned, despite falling within the LIMIT. The solution was to add the HAVING clause. (Honestly, I'm still not sure -why-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it to the ON clause:

```
LEFT JOIN votes ON (users.id = votes.userid) AND (votes.timestamp BETWEEN date_add(NOW(),INTERVAL -24 HOUR) AND NOW())
```

If you put the condition in the WHERE clause, you'll potentially be eliminating the user completely, negating the purpose of the LEFT JOIN.  The ON clause won't have this problem.

Comment: Good stuff! Makes sense. Awesome, I can give you a green check... soon.